# AWS cognito user authentication with laravel

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-5.1, amazon-cognito

We are trying to implement Amazon Cognito services for user authentication with our built in laravel 5.1 application. We are looking for a composer package for laravel 5.1 that allow to Amazon Cognito User Pools, registering user's into User Pools, password resets etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AWS SDK for PHP using Composer. See the following quoted steps of this [guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/installation.html).

> 1. Open a terminal window and navigate to the directory where your project is stored. Composer is installed on a per-project basis.
> 2. Download and install Composer in your project directory. If you have `curl` installed, you can use the following command:
>
>    ```
>    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
>    ```
>
>    When the installation script finishes, a `composer.phar` file will be created in the directory where you ran the installer.
> 3. Create a file at the root level of your project called composer.json and add the following dependency for the AWS PHP SDK:
>
>    ```
>    {
>        "require": {
>            "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*"
>        }
>    }
>    ```
> 4. Install the dependencies by running Composer's install command:
>
>    ```
>    php composer.phar install
>    ```
>
>    This will create a `vendor` directory in your project with the required libraries and an autoloader script used to load them for your
>      project.
> 5. Require Composer's autoloader by adding the following line to your code's bootstrap process (typically in `index.php`):
>
>    ```
>    require '/path/to/sdk/vendor/autoload.php';
>    ```
>
>    Your code is now ready to use the AWS SDK for PHP!

AWS has added Cognito User Pools management in [Version 3.32.7](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/releases/tag/3.32.7). You may have a look at [AWS Service Provider for Laravel](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel) as well for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old, but for someone looking for such package check this out, I think this is what you need

https://github.com/black-bits/laravel-cognito-auth